# Navicat can't connect mysql server via ssh

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh, navicat

I can connect the server via ssh and login the mysql via `mysql -u root -h localhost -p` without any problem. But why Navicat's ssh login doesn't work?

Server Environment:

```
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.67, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1
```

Why this error info prints the public ip of the server when I'm using localhost to connect mysql?

Navicat Settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're using the "Public Key" method to login to ssh with root. Root login for ssh is disabled on many systems. You're certain it works to login in with root over regular ssh?

If you have access to ssh_config, you could try to enable regular password-based authentication on ssh and then try that in Navicat, preferrably with a non-root user.

Comment: +1 for the first part, +0 for the second, makes +0.5, rounds to +1.